# changing supermicro bios settings using a script via serial port

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool, ipmiutil

I was wondering how can I write a script that automatically changes bios settings.
I was looking all over how to write such script but haven't found one yet.

My main goal is from a Linux machine to run putty or Minicom to update the settings that I want.